# How do i get my DiscordClient's uptime in D#+?

Tags: discord, dsharp+

Does anyone know how to get the `DiscordClient` Uptime in D#+ And how to fix the Connection terminated error?

Basically the **Uptime** is the time that the bot was on for.

And i wanna make a command that will try to get the bot's uptime and send it in an `DiscordEmbed` (embed)

A reply would be soo much appreciated thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The easiest way to do this is to add a `DateTime` variable to your main async that connects your bot.

```cs
public static DateTime startTime = DateTime.Now;

public static async Task MainAsync()
{
  var discord = new DiscordClient(Settings.ClientSettings);
  //provide all your settings for the discord client here
  //Call the discord.Ready event to reset the startTime to when the bot connects
  discord.Ready += async (discordClient, readyEventArgs) =>
  {
    startTime = DateTime.Now; //This will set the startTime to the ms the bot connects
  };
  await discord.ConnectAsync();
  await Task.Delay(-1);
}
```

You can now call this with the within the allowed scope of your class by using `ClassName.startTime` and get the time since this with `DateTime.Now - ClassName.startTime`. You can then manipulate the way this is shown however you'd like.